# Change namespace of a deployed clickonce application

Tags: c#, namespaces, clickonce, application-settings

I made a bit of a namespace spelling mistake and I wish to correct it.   My application currently uses Application.Settings to store a bulk of the user's information.  If I refactor my namespace to be spelled correctly, will the application settings file essentially get wiped because it can't find the new namespace in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that ClickOnce will see this as a different application, so yes, the application settings would be "lost".  I had to do this once myself, and I lost all the settings.  Users had to install it as a new application and set up their personal inf all over again.

I never gt a definitive answer on why this was, but here's my guess:

If ClickOnce behaved otherwise, it would be too easy for someone to replace your app with a malicious one of their own, so from a security perspective, this makes sense.

However, I could be wrong.  You could try it, and see.  If the settings are lost, you can always revert (assuming you're using source control).

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this before, but it looks like you should be able to just change the *app*.exe.config filename to your app's new name and it will read it just fine, assuming you can script that into your deployment.